# Simplifying an identity from complex analysis

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

```
z = r (Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])
```

I want Mathematica to return `True` when I evaluate

```
FullSimplify[z^n == r^n (Cos[n θ] + I Sin[n θ])]
```

but it doesn't simpplify the equality. Why?

Comment: It doesn't retun True here for the same reason it doesn't return True for a==b. You are presumaing some relationship between r, theta, and z, but Matheamtica doesn't know this.

Answer (score 3):

```
z = r (Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ]);

FullSimplify[z^n == r^n (Cos[n θ] + I Sin[n θ])] // PowerExpand

(*  True  *)
```

The use of [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html) implies the necessary assumptions

Answer (score 2):

You can find conditions under which equality holds, but you have to let Mathematica know about the relationship between r and z...

```
FullSimplify[r Exp[I n t] == r Cos[n t] + I r Sin[n t] && 
          t \[Element] Reals && n \[Element] Reals]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following code:

```
   result1 = FullSimplify[z^n == r^n (Cos[n \[Theta]] + I Sin[n \[Theta]])]
   PowerExpand[result1, Assumptions -> True]
```

This is the real identity  without any conditions.