# Why do none of FullSimplify, Simplify, and Refine simplify my expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I used three functions to simplify.

First

```
FullSimplify[Exp[y] > Exp[x], y > x > 0 && y ∈ Reals && x ∈ Reals]
(*Out: Exp[y] > Exp[x]  *)
```

Second

```
Simplify[Exp[y] > Exp[x],  y > x > 0 && y ∈ Reals && x ∈ Reals]
(*Out: Exp[y] > Exp[x]  *)
```

Third

```
Refine[Exp[y] > Exp[x], y > x > 0 && y ∈ Reals && x ∈ Reals]
(*Out: Exp[y] > Exp[x]  *)
```

I think I've given enough conditions to get `True` for the result just as with

```
Simplify[y > x, y > x > 0 && y ∈ Reals && x ∈ Reals]
(*Out: True   *)
```

Comment: Related: [(132158)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132158/simplifying-an-identity-from-complex-analysis).

Comment: This works: `With[{assum = y > x > 0 && y ∈ Reals && x ∈ Reals}, Simplify[Reduce[assum \[Implies] Exp[y] > Exp[x], Reals], assum]]`. -- Again, I can't explain why there are these edge cases between different functions. The `*Simplify` functions tend to transform the expression into simpler expressions (fewer leaves); if there was a transformation that would change `Exp[y] > Exp[x]` into `y > x`, then it should work. Apparently there isn't one. (It's only true over the reals, which might be why.) `Reduce` tends to be more robust and exacting, but it only works on relations.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - you can simplify to `assum = y > x > 0` since the presence of `y` and `x` in an inequality implies that they are real,

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, I know. Thanks. (If you're curious, I often just copy & paste the OP's code and don't fiddle with it unless and until it seems worth it. It's hardly an answer, imo, though many times, the OP isn't really interested in the question *Why?* but actually just in workarounds.)

Comment: `Refine` seems a bit sketchy with `Exp`. For example `Refine[Exp[y] > Pi, y > 2]` returns unrefined `Exp[y] > Pi` but `Refine[Exp[y] > Pi, y > 3]` returns true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following return `True`:

```
Resolve[Implies[ForAll[{x, y}, y > x > 0], Exp[y] > Exp[x]]]

FullSimplify[Implies[ForAll[{x, y}, y > x > 0], Exp[y] > Exp[x]]]
```